# How do we show $a_{n} = 2^{n}\sin(x/2^{n}) \rightarrow x$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Just curious as to how this argument runs.  I know I have to fix $\epsilon > 0$ and show there is an $N$ such that $|a_{n} - x| < \epsilon$.  Only I'm stuck finding the appropriate bounds for $2^{n}\sin(x/2^{n})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$2^n\sin\frac x{2^n}=x\frac{\sin\frac x{2^n}}{\frac x{2^n}}$$

and now use that

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{\sin f(x)}{f(x)}=1\;,\;\;\text{whenever}\;\;\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=0$$